# How to send Alert Notification for Failed Job in Google Dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, stackdriver

I am wondering if there is a way to hook in some notifications for jobs submitted in Dataproc. We are planning to use Dataproc to run a streaming application 24/7. But Dataproc doesnt seem to have a way to notify for failed jobs.

Just wondering if Google StackDriver can be used by any means.

Thanks
Suren

Answer (score 2):

Sure, StackDriver can be used to set an alert policy on a defined log-metric.
For example, you can set a **Metric Absence** policy which will monitor for successful job completion and alert if it's missing for a defined period of time.

Go to [Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) in your console and set a filter:

```
resource.type="cloud_dataproc_cluster"
jsonPayload.message:"completed with exit code 0"
```

Click on *Create Metric*, after filling the details you'll be redirected to the log-metrics page where you'll be able to create an alert from the metric

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I inverted it to `exit code 1` so that it notifies me every time a job fails and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the answer above, log-based metrics can be coerced to provide the OP required functionality. But, `metric absence` for long-running jobs would imply you would have to wait for longer than a guess at the longest job running time (and you still might get an alert if the job takes a bit longer but is not failing). What 'we' really want is a way of monitoring and alerting on job status `failed`, or, service completion message indicating failure (like your example), such that we are **alerted immediately**. Yes, you can define a Stackdriver log-based metric, looking for specific strings or values indicating failure, and this 'works', but metrics are measures that are counted, for example 'how many jobs failed', and require inconvenient workarounds to turn alert-from-metric into a simple 'this job failed' alert. To make this work, for example, the alert filters on a metric and also needs to specify a mean aggregator over an interval to fire an alert. Nasty :(